# Known message attack on ENC-MAC with AES encryption

Tags: aes, mac

The assignment I have is as follows:

Let $l=2^{128}$ and let $x$ be a random integer satisfying $0\le x \le l$

Let $\oplus $ be the XOR operator and $E_k$ an AES encryption with $key=k$

Let the signature of a string $M=m_{1}||m_{2}\dots||m_{n} $ where $||$ denotes concatenation of strings where $m_i $ is a binary string of $128$ bits

Now assume the signature $$ S\left(x,M\right)=\left\langle x,\sum_{i=1}^{n}E_{k}\left(m_{i}\oplus E_{k}\left(i+x\right)\right)\mod l\right\rangle  $$

Design an known message attack to forge signatures.

---

Using brute force to break down AES is impossible so there must be some clever trick.
I tried using $n=2 $ and using the known message $$ S\left(x,M\right)=\left\langle x,E_{k}\left(m_{1}\oplus\left(E_{k}\left(x+1\right)\right)\right)+E_{k}\left(m_{2}\oplus\left(E_{k}\left(x+2\right)\right)\right)\right\rangle  $$

We can construct another string $T=t_{1}||t_{2} $ and we want the parameters inside $E_k$ to be equal:
$$ m_{1}\oplus\left(E_{k}\left(x+1\right)\right)=t_{2}\oplus\left(E_{k}\left(x+2\right)\right)\Rightarrow \\t_{2}=m_{1}\oplus\left(E_{k}\left(x+1\right)\right)\oplus\left(E_{k}\left(x+2\right)\right) \\\\$$
With the same logic we can deduce $$
t_{1}=m_{2}\oplus\left(E_{k}\left(x+2\right)\right)\oplus\left(E_{k}\left(x+1\right)\right) $$
obviously if $t_1=m_1 , t_2=m_2 $ it will satisfy the equations, but is there any way to find other $t_1,t_2 $ that satisfy the conditions if we don't know $E_k(x+1)$ or $E_k(x+2)$ ?
Is there perhaps another method to find an attack on this signature?

Comment: Does the key $k$ is fixed? Also, in your solution, how do you access the internal values?

Comment: Yes, $k$ is a fixed(unknown to atyacker) 128 bit key. One can't access the internal values, only a few messages and their signatures.